# Memory leak in tomcat web application by EventBus

Tags: java, memory-leaks, tomcat7

I am getting these logs in my catalina.out when un-deploying my application from tomcat. Its a java based restlet service on tomcat 7.

```
SEVERE: The web application [/my-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus$2] (value [com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus$2@f120fcf]) and a value of type [java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 29, 2015 3:49:52 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/my-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus$3] (value [com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus$3@6acbe6c3]) and a value of type [java.lang.Boolean] (value [false]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

I am initializing EventBus like this in my restlet application class -

```
private EventBus eventBus = new EventBus();
```

In the application start, i register the required EventHandler class

```
@Override
public synchronized void start() throws Exception {
eventBus.register(new EvenHandlerClass());     
...
}
```

This event bus is used by different classes for posting events. The application provides a getter method only to access this event bus and post events.
I check around but i could not find if we need to close the event bus or shut it down someway.
Am i missing something here ?

Comment: You're probably ok. That log line is telling you Tomcat is going to stop threads so your ThreadLocals get GCed.

Comment: I am facing OutOfMemory exception the same server and i fear that is due to this problem. I am not able to take heap dump there due to some other exception being thrown by jmap.

Comment: Does EventHandlerClass hold onto any interesting references? It might help to unregister it on shutdown.

Comment: I check the EventHandler class, seems fine to me. Going to try the unregistering at application stop.

Comment: Tried with unregistering the eventhandler class - Didnt work.

Comment: You really need to get a heap dump to get much more insight into this.